# Проблемы с пониманием работы оператора switch

Tags: php, switch

```
switch (Wo_UrlAvailable()) {
   case "https://www.google/": {
      echo "Google is available";
      break;
   }
   case "https://yandex.ru/": {
      echo "Yandex is available";
      break;
   }
}
```

Как передать значение case (https://www.google/ || https://yandex.ru/) в качестве аргумента для функции Wo_UrlAvailable(), что является аргументом для switch.

Wo_UrlAvailable() - проверяет доступен ли url (проще говоря, делает ping и возвращает результат true/false, если сайт респонсится то true)

Comment: Если Wo_UrlAvailable проверяет гугл ИЛИ яндекс - то никак

Comment: хорошо, спасибо. Тогда по старинке сделаю через if/else if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то надо так:

```
switch (true) {
   case Wo_UrlAvailable('google') {
      echo "Google is available";
      break;
   }
   case Wo_UrlAvailable('yandex'): {
      echo "Yandex is available";
      break;
   }
}
```

Соответственно метод `Wo_UrlAvailable` должен принимать один строковый параметр с наименованием сервиса, внутри проверяется доступность

Comment: Уже вижу что это то, что нужно! Всё на деле оказывается было очень легко... Спасибо!